# Default Value for tomorrow at specific time

Tags: 2007, calculated-column, default-value

Say I'm currently using a Date/Time field for workflow purposes, the default value being `Today+1`. That gives the time at 12:00am tomorrow, which is great.

Is there a way to always give the default value to, say, 9am tomorrow (regardless of what time it is today)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this formula as default value :

```
=Today+1+(9/24)
```

this should do the trick :)

times are stored as fraction, so using this method you can also specify minute, say you want to set default value as 9:30 AM then you can write

```
=Today+1+(9/24)+(30/(24*60))
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of only `Today+1` use `=Today+1+(9/24)`

Comment: Eh, Diptarag already answered the same. sorry for duplicate.

Comment: no worry buddy, answering is essential, who answers does not matter :)